# CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS works only with hardcoded string

Tags: php, php-curl

Having some weird issues with performing a POST request using curl. I am trying to scrape a website for some information. The website is using written using ASPX.

I am currently performing a GET request to obtain the VIEWSTATE, VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and the EVENTVALIDATION values. This code works fine.

```
$html = $this->hhb_curl_exec2($ch, $this->url, $debugHeaders, $debugCookies, $debugRequest);
$domd = new \DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML($html);
assert(is_object($domd));
$__VIEWSTATE = $domd->getElementById('__VIEWSTATE')->getAttribute('value');
$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR =  $domd->getElementById('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')->getAttribute('value');
$__EVENTVALIDATION = $domd->getElementById('__EVENTVALIDATION')->getAttribute('value');
```

My code to perform the POST request

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ( 'Expect :', 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Connection: keep-alive', 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8', 'DNT: 1','Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1', 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36', ) ) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
$html = $this->hhb_curl_exec2($ch, $this->url, $debugHeaders, $debugCookies, $debugRequest);
```

I have tried using the following methods to format my data to pass into CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.
- http_build_query
- formatted string
and it all fails.

But if I were to echo the http_build_query output and hardcode the value into $data, it works. Trying to follow this logic, I tried using ob_start and ob_get_clean into a variable and it still doesn't work. I was thinking it might have to do with encoding so I tried with urlencode, rawurlencode and etc and still doesn't work.

Have been on this for 4 days. Anyone have any ideas?

---

This the data that I am populating into the array

```
        $data = [];
        $data['__EVENTTARGET'] = '';
        $data['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = '';
        $data['txtID'] = '123';
        $data['Type'] = 'Check';
        $data['__VIEWSTATE']  = '/wEPDwUKLTgxMjY3NTc3OQ9kFgICAw9kFggCDA9kFgICAw8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCDQ9kFgICAw8PFgIfAGhkZAIOD2QWAgIDDw8WAh8AaGRkAhMPDxYCHgRUZXh0BQM2ODFkZBgBBQhDYXB0Y2hhMQ8FJGU3MWM0NWRkLTc5NTYtNDg1OS05NjBjLThkZGVlMjg5NjRkYWSfOThWHvPz4/TL+UaGirQZ5RboSnTC9dUIpDr5cInhgQ==';
        $data['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = '259A63A1';
        $data['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = '/wEdAATzTFkZdU/CJ5dXkuY45iU6kpmFQIiHR062LxhkThIrE5l/kxSnaCiVP8n0gK4NzCOkWRDoSjN1G98r+I9h/rD7Tmr9zlIbeGS1P8q5MIlYg1K5J4JlQdGE6eaZgYCE+Ic=';
```

And the hardcoded values is simply to use http_build_query on the $t,
what I usually get is

`__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&txtID=123&Type=Check&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=259A63A1&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKLTgxMjY3NTc3OQ9kFgICAw9kFggCDA9kFgICAw8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCDQ9kFgICAw8PFgIfAGhkZAIOD2QWAgIDDw8WAh8AaGRkAhMPDxYCHgRUZXh0BQM2ODFkZBgBBQhDYXB0Y2hhMQ8FJGU3MWM0NWRkLTc5NTYtNDg1OS05NjBjLThkZGVlMjg5NjRkYWSfOThWHvPz4%2FTL%2BUaGirQZ5RboSnTC9dUIpDr5cInhgQ%3D%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAATzTFkZdU%2FCJ5dXkuY45iU6kpmFQIiHR062LxhkThIrE5l%2FkxSnaCiVP8n0gK4NzCOkWRDoSjN1G98r%2BI9h%2FrD7Tmr9zlIbeGS1P8q5MIlYg1K5J4JlQdGE6eaZgYCE%2BIc%3D`

---

More detailed explanation on what's happening.

If I were to use this method to build the string to post, it doesnt work,

```
$ev = urlencode( $__EVENTVALIDATION );
$vs = urlencode( $__VIEWSTATE );

$apc = 'Type=Check&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__EVENTTARGET='.
        "&__EVENTVALIDATION={$ev}".
        "&__VIEWSTATE={$vs}".
        "&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR={$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR}&txtID={$id}";
```

However, if I were to do it this way, it works, for some really weird reason.

```
$ev = urlencode( '/wEdAATzTFkZdU/CJ5dXkuY45iU6kpmFQIiHR062LxhkThIrE5l/kxSnaCiVP8n0gK4NzCOkWRDoSjN1G98r+I9h/rD7Tmr9zlIbeGS1P8q5MIlYg1K5J4JlQdGE6eaZgYCE+Ic=' );
$vs = urlencode( '/wEPDwUKLTgxMjY3NTc3OQ9kFgICAw9kFggCDA9kFgICAw8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCDQ9kFgICAw8PFgIfAGhkZAIOD2QWAgIDDw8WAh8AaGRkAhMPDxYCHgRUZXh0BQM2ODFkZBgBBQhDYXB0Y2hhMQ8FJGU3MWM0NWRkLTc5NTYtNDg1OS05NjBjLThkZGVlMjg5NjRkYWSfOThWHvPz4/TL+UaGirQZ5RboSnTC9dUIpDr5cInhgQ==' );

$apc = 'Type=Check&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__EVENTTARGET='.
        "&__EVENTVALIDATION={$ev}".
        "&__VIEWSTATE={$vs}".
        "&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR={$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR}&txtID={$id}";
```

Comment: can you show what is there in `$data` actually? and `But if I were to echo the http_build_query output and hardcode the value into $data, it works.`? that on too (means hardcoded-one)

Comment: @Anant, added to my main post

Comment: You could build that string yourself starting from $data array

Comment: @Cristian, i have tried but doesnt work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the real cause of my issues, the website I am scrapping had some extra checks being handled on the server side and decided to not post back the error.

I just had to set a delay of 3 seconds for it to work.

Sorry, guys.